# how to submit a form via ajax from modal box using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I'm having a tough time submitting a form using ajax from a modal box.

```
        $( "#modal" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit Form": function() {

                    $("#my-form").submit(function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                            $.post('myurl', function(data) {
                                $('.result').html(data);
                            });
                    });

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

When i try to submit the form by clicking the "submit form" button nothing actually happens.

All I'm trying to do is submit the form via ajax using the modalbox button. Then the controller would return a simple text "form processed" and then the `.result` will be updated with the response from the controller.

Edit

My html form looks like this:

```
<form id="my-form" action="myurl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload file</legend>
        <p>
                            <label for="fileData">File</label>
            <br />
            <input id="fileData" name="fileData" type="file" value=""/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit) which has an .ajaxSubmit() function. Should be something like this:

```
$("#my-form").ajaxSubmit({
  success: function(response) {
    $('.result').html(response);
  }, error: function(e) {
    $('.result').html(e);
  }
});
```

`beforeSubmit` - pre-submit callback

`success` - post-submit callback

`error` - fail-response callback

Answer (score 0):

#### Please change these lines to include your `<form>` data:

```
$.post($(this).parent('form').attr('action'), $(this).parent('form').serialize(), function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

***PS:** I am not sure if sending files work out on AJAX. Logically it should work.*

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working for me. the form i'm submitting has a file upload button

Comment: Do you have a form first of all? Can you update your question with the HTML Code?

Comment: please see the html for the form

Comment: @birdy Please check this out. Say if it is working, else show us the full HTML in a hosted way, so that we can check what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following markup

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='myurl'>
           <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload file</legend>
    <p>
                        <label for="fileData">File</label>
        <br />
        <input id="fileData" name="fileData" type="file"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
                    </form>
```

**TRY AVOIDING VALUE="" ATRIBUTE FOR FILE TYPE**

Then your jquery would be using the [ajaxForm()](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

like

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#fileData').live('change', function(){ 
$("#my-form").ajaxForm({}).submit();
});
});
```